# Flask Route Working Locally but Not with Azure Devops

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a Flask-SQL Alchemy App. First I debug it locally using VSC and everything works correctly. I can access both routes via http://127.0.0.1:5000/healthcheck

I have two routes:
(1)

```
# Healthcheck route to confirm that the app is running correctly.
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request

blueprint = Blueprint('healthcheck_blueprint', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/healthcheck', methods=['GET'])
def health_check():

    return jsonify({"status": "The App is up and running =;)"}), 200
```

And (2):

```
# Healthcheck route to confirm that the app is running correctly.
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request

blueprint = Blueprint('tree_blueprint', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/tree/view', methods=['GET'])
def health_check():

    return jsonify({"status": "Tree"}), 200
```

When I run the app locally everything is fine and both routes are accessible.

When I deploy to Azure Devops only (1) works and on (2) I get a 404 error.
The url is https://[xxxxx].azurewebsites.net//healthcheck
It seems that I cannot add any new routes for some reason.

Note: They deployment on Azure is succesful.

[update] I have noticed that some other changes are also not reflected although I can see them in the Azure repo. Could it be some caching issue ?

Any thoughts much appreciated.
BR
pk